# Translation for "inclusive/extractive economic institutions" (Why Nations Fail)

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I'm reading "Why Nations Fail" at the moment and the core essence of the book is the differentiation between **inclusive economic institutions** and **extractive economic institutions**.

Now, I figured from the context of the book what those meant, but I can't seem to find a German term for both of them, even though I'm a native speaker.

I thought about things like:

- altruistisch/egoistisch
- kooperativ/profitorientiert
- Reziprozität/Wettkampf

But none of them really express those terms from the book correctly.

What would be the best German translation for this?

#### To clarify about the meaning of the words

- inclusive economic insititutions: allow and encourage participation by the **great mass of people** in economic activities
- extractive economic insititutions: **remove the majority of the population** from participation in political or economic affairs

If I would "translate" it to politics I'd probably compare it with pluralism/hegemony.

Comment: You maybe didnt' see it, but you are allowed to ask questions in German here

Answer (score 3):

Auf der [deutschen Wikipedia-Seite zu dem Buch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warum_Nationen_scheitern) ist von inklusiven und extraktiven Institutionen die Rede. Beides hätte ich jetzt tatsächlich genauso übersetzt, ich verstehe nicht ganz, wie du auf diese sehr speziellen Übersetzungen kommst. Bei derart speziellen Begriffen aus Fachliteratur würde ich die Übersetzung immer so nah wie möglich am Ursprungsbegriff ausrichten, da brauchst du nicht das Rad neu zu erfinden.

Comment: Ich als Muttersprachler ohne speziellen VWL/BWL-Hintergrund kann mir unter einer inklusiven oder extraktiven Institution gar nichts vorstellen, müsste ich halt erstmal nachschlagen. Falls OP eine Übersetzung für mich oder ein ähnlich unbedarftes Publikum anfertigt, trägt eine Übersetzung ähnlich seiner ersten beiden Beispiele zum Verständnis bei. (das dritte nicht, denn Reziprozität gehört auch nicht in meinen Alltagswortschatz :) ) - Bei eiiner Übersetzung für Fachpublikum bin ich bei Dir, wenn das auch im Deutschen etablierte Fachbegriffe sind.

Comment: Naja, es sind halt Fachbegriffe und ich finde ein "dumbing down" nicht unbedingt förderlich, wenn man nicht 100%-ig synonyme Begriffe verwendet. Möglicherweise verstehen nämlich die Leute vom Fach nicht, auf welches Konzept man sich bezieht, wenn man etwa von "altruistischen Institutionen" redet. Kennt jemand die englischsprachige Quelle, ist es sehr einfach, gedanklich eine Brücke von "inclusive" zu "inklusiv" zu schlagen, andererseits erweckt man den Anschein, sich auf ein vollkommen anderes gedankliches Konstrukt zu beziehen, wenn man dieses Mapping nicht explizit unterstreicht.

Comment: Wie gesagt, ich würde es davon abhängig machen. wer das Zielpublikum ist und wie gut ich verstanden werden will.

Comment: Ich kann deine Meinung hierzu sehr gut verstehen, allerdings werden Wörter wie _include_ und _extract_ im englischen Sprachgebrauch deutlich mehr verwendet als die deutschen Pendants _inkludieren_ und _extrahieren_. Insofern würde es mich interessieren ob es hierfür keine "bessere" Übersetzung gibt. Danke aber für deine Antwort!

Comment: @MauriceLegoland Einerseits. Andererseits sollten Sie sich aber wohl die Frage stellen, ob es so sinnvoll ist, eine andere Übersetzung zu wählen, denn das Buch liegt ja schon auf Deutsch vor - und dort werden offenbar die Begriffe "inklusiv"/"extraktiv" verwendet (vgl. die zweite Rezensionsnotiz im Wikipedia-Artikel, die die Begriffe als Zitate ausweist). Verlagsübersetzungen sind natürlich nicht immer toll, aber man läuft Gefahr, das deutsche Publikum mit einem von der deutschen Ausgabe abweichenden Begriffspaar u.U. eher zu verwirren als mit der evtl. etwas ungelenken "Original"-Übersetzung.

Answer (score 2):

Wie wäre es mit **integrativen** vs. **ausschließenden** Institutionen?

*Einschließend* als Gegensatz zu *ausschließend* ist nicht ganz überzeugend, weil das Einschließen wie im Gefängnis mit anklingt.

Ich kenne weder das Buch, noch die vorgestellte Theorie, aber von Deiner Beschreibung treffen die von Dir vorgeschlagenen Begriffe die Sache ja gar nicht.

Comment: Danke! Gefällt mir sehr gut und klingt auch gut!